# How to use Regular Expression to format a date?

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a application in ASP.NET and my date format is `dd-mm-yyyy` so therefore required a help to build regular expression for it.

Comment: You could also use `C#`.  `DateTime thisDate1 = new DateTime(2011, 6, 10);
Console.WriteLine("Today is " + thisDate1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".");`  Or see all conversion examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this from [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info):

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$
```

It's good to use a tool such as [Nregex](http://www.nregex.com/nregex/default.aspx) or [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) when you're trying out regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

from [DotNetSlackers](http://dotnetslackers.com/Regex/re-16542_Regex_matches_a_date_in_dd_mm_yyyy_format.aspx), regex for dd/mm/yyyy:

```
^(((((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])))|((31\/((0[13578])|(1[02])))|((29|30)\/((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2])))))\/((20[0-9][0-9])|(19[0-9][0-9])))|((29\/02\/(19|20)(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))))$
```

Modified to work with dd-mm-yyyy

```
^(((((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))-((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])))|((31-((0[13578])|(1[02])))|((29|30)-((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2])))))-((20[0-9][0-9])|(19[0-9][0-9])))|((29-02-(19|20)(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))))$
```

Comment: Some problem with the modified expression..its only accepting 29 and 30th of every month not other dates :)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the feedback. FYI, fixed it for fun :)